# WCF proxy doesn't know about callback when using generic base interface in service

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I'm writing some generic code that can be re-used across a number of WCF services. I've been able to successfully use a generic interface and base class, then add a derived interface and class that only specifies the type to use:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IGenericContract<T>
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomething(T param);
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService : IGenericContract<string> {}

// Re-usable generic base class
public class GenericService<T> : IGenericContract<T>
{
    public void DoSomething(T param)
    {
    }
}

// Specific service implementation
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class Service : GenericService<string>, IService
{
}
```

When I host an instance of `Service` and generate the proxy, I get a `DoSomething()` method with the string type param as expected:

```
public void DoSomething(string param) {
    base.Channel.DoSomething(param);
}
```

This works great until I try to add a callback using the same technique:

```
public interface IGenericCallback<T>
{
    [OperationContract]
    void DoSomethingOnClient(T param);
}
public interface ICallback : IGenericCallback<string>
{
}

// Add CallbackContract type to service
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallback))]
public interface IService : IGenericContract<string> { }
```

The generated proxy doesn't know anything about `ICallback`. Why is this and is there a way around it?

Comment: Are you registering your service as `GenericService<String>`, or as `Service`?

Comment: I'm hosting a `Service` class instance as the WCF service